# SVC Host service not visible in Svchost viewer

Tags: windows, networking, port, netstat, svchost

Some port required by my application was put in `TIME_WAIT` status by svchost which I found by running netstat. I used this application called Svchost Viewer to track the PID corresponding to the service but it doesnt show up. Is there another way to test/find this?

Comment: SvcHost was "blocking" it? That doesn't sound right. how do you believe a service blocks a port, unless it is the windows firewall service? How could netstat tell you that a port was "blocked"?  If you want to enumerate teh windows services in a svchost instance, make note of its PID, and run in an elevated command prompt `tasklist /SVC > c:\temp\tasks.txt`. after the command completes look at the tasks.txt, and it shoudl show you what services are in it. Then you would have to stop and disable that service. but I don't think thats actually what the problem is. processes don't "block" ports.

Comment: @FrankThomas Sorry I should have phrased that better...that port was put in TIME_WAIT status by svchost.

Comment: well, if your app is using a port that another program is using, then your program really needs to use a differant port. TIME_WAIT refers to the state of a TCP connection, and usually indicates a connection that is being closed locally, and is waiting for a final fin/ack from the report peer. Either way, only the process that opens a port can use it, so your app must be trying to use a port that a service has already opened. that generally means you should pick another port for your app, between 2000 and 40000.

Answer (score 0):

Individual services being handled by a Svchost don't have PIDs, as they are operating under that individual SVCHost's process.

You can use `tasklist /svc` to determine which services are running under which (SVCHost) PID.

Once you have that list, stop each of the listed services one at a time, and run NetStat again, until you figure out which service is blocking the port.